# How do I access FTP URL from solaris?

Tags: unix, ftp, solaris, wget, hosts

I need to access an ftp url (  ftp://ftp.cmegroup.com/pub/settle  ) from my solaris box.
if I paste this URL into a browser, it works fine.

I tried wget   and ftp  ftp://ftp.cmegroup.com/pub/settle

Resolving ftp.cmegroup.com... failed: Host not found.*

but I get host not found error.

How do I resolve this? which file in /etc do I need to make an entry for this to work?

Comment: Can cou ping the host 'ftp.cmegroup.com' from your solaris box? It looks to me that you are having somekind of network issues. edit: or perhaps DNS issues, you can try using the IP that resolves to that domain (216.178.212.20)

Comment: Does remote server has restriction on any such connection?
Connecting via browser will be on http but you are trying to connect via ftp!

Comment: nope. am not able to do a ping too

Comment: the browser is on the same solaris box?

Comment: @BRATVADDI If you can not ping to the host it is no problem with either wget or some other download tool. Make sure your network connectivity is ok and your DNS is correctly set. To solve this you do not need to change anything in /etc

Comment: Are you behind a firewall?  Do you need to use proxies to get out?  If so, you'll need to set the `ftp_proxy` environment variable for wget.

Comment: If your browser uses proxy, it could be the proxy doing name resolution, not your local Solaris DNS client. This is why the browser works and `wget` does not.

Answer (score 1):

this was acheieved using ftp_proxy in my .wgetrc file. I had to go through a proxy to do this.

Comment: just reread my question. apologies, I did not mention a proxy was used.